# rails 4 dynamic select menus file.js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, coffeescript

I've a super noob question to make!

railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised 
 the application of the episode is very simple but I need of a dynamic menu in my application that is "a bit" longer.
In the episode is used a file people.js.coffe that run when the app create a new person

in my app this file could be called when I create a new modulo1 (at localhost:3000/users/1/modulo1s/new)

the question is: where I must write the coffe script text? in what file? (application.js.coffe, modulo1s.js.coffe...) I tried to put it everywhere but it didn't work!

```
    application.js

       jQuery ->
       $('#categorie_id').parent().hide()
       categories = $('#categorie_id').html()
       $('#_macrocategorie_id').change ->
       macrocategorie = $('#macrocategorie_id :selected').text()
       options = $(categories).filter("optgroup[label='#{macrocategorie}']").html()
       if options
       $('#categorie_id').html(options)
       $('#categorie_id').parent().show()
       else
       $('#categorie_id').empty()
       $('#categorie_id').parent().hide()
```

form

```
        <div class="form-field">
        <%= f.label :macrocategorie_id %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select :macrocategorie_id, Macrocategorie.order(:nome), :id, 
                                  :nome, {:prompt => "Seleziona una Macrocategoria"} %>
        <%= f.label :categorie_id %>
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :categorie_id, 
                             Macrocategorie.order(:nome),:categories,:nome, :id,:nome,  
                                             {:prompt => "Seleziona una Categoria"} %>
        </div>
```

if it could be useful

```
     class Macrocategorie < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :categories,class_name: 'Categorie'
     has_many :modulo1s
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
     attr_accessible :nome, :categories_attributes
     end



     class Categorie < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :macrocategorie,class_name: 'Macrocategorie'
     has_many :modulo1s
     attr_accessible :nome, :macrocategorie_id, :microcategories_attributes
     end
```

Comment: can you post your layout and your application.js files?

Comment: although you can but i wont recommend you to write your code in application.js, instead you should make a new file and then require that file inside application.js or if you have require_tree then it'll automatically takes care of it

Comment: ok, I think I understand but how i could require the file? in the example of the question the file is js.coffee i could create a file with that extension? thanks for your time @Mandeep

Comment: you want to rename your application.js file?

Comment: no no! I want to create a new file but i can't choose an appropriate name and extension! I'd like to know how require this file in application.js

Comment: lets suppose your file is named file.js.coffeescript then simply write //= require file in your application.js or if you have //= require_tree . then it will automatically require all the files inside app/assets/javascript folder

Comment: ah ok! It's really simple! thanks @Mandeep I hope then creating this file the app works filnally!

Comment: good luck and btw read docs first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html :)

Comment: I think I made some errors in the .js file don't work..but thanks for your help! I learned a lot :D

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: no error but it doesn't do anything! It seems there is something wrong in the javascript file and can't read the ids from the tables..it will be a long night for me! :D